# Help! How to solve: dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/tachidesk-server_0.6.4-0ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  tachidesk-server
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/96.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 108 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 181083 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../tachidesk-server_0.6.4-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking tachidesk-server (0.6.4-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/tachidesk-server_0.6.4-0ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/usr/lib/systemd/system/tachidesk-server.service.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
         Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/tachidesk-server_0.6.4-0ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

i have googled the issues and instructed 
**solution 1**

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get -f  install tachidesk-server
```

**solution 2**

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i /var/cache/apt/archives/tachidesk-server_0.6.4-0ubuntu1_all.deb
```

**solution 3**

i have downloaded the deb file of tachidesk-server then

```
sudo apt install ./Tachidesk-Server-v0.6.4-r1119-debian-all.deb
or 
sudo dpkg -i Tachidesk-Server-v0.6.4-r1119-debian-all.deb
```

but these solution are same the problem.
i am grateful if will solve the problem.

Comment: What is your OS? Debian or Ubuntu?